# Show that $\mathscr{E}(\Omega)$ is a complete metric space, i.e. the Frechet Space is complete.

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, complete-spaces

Show that $\mathscr{E}(\Omega)$ is a complete metric space, i.e. the Frechet Space.

So we must show that $\mathscr{E}(\Omega)$ is complete. Thus let ${f_{n}}$ be a Cauchy Sequence in $\mathscr{E}(\Omega)$, we must show that ${f_{n}}$ converges to some $f$ in $\mathscr{E}(\Omega)$.

Since ${f_{n}}$  is a Cauchy sequence then it must bounded, i.e. there exists and $M$ such that $|{f_{n}}| \leq M$ for all $n\geq \mathbb{N}$. Set $Q = \{f \in \mathscr{E}(\Omega) \mid \text{there exists infinitely many $n$ such that $f_{n} \geq f$} \}$. Indeed $M\in Q$ and M is an upperbound of Q. That is, $Q$ is a nonempty subset of $\mathscr{E}(\Omega)$ that is bounded above. Hence,

$\beta =$ sup $Q$ exists, i.e. $\beta \in \mathscr{E}(\Omega)$

From here I go on to show that $\beta + \epsilon/2 \notin Q$ and $f_{n} < \beta + \epsilon/2$ for infinitely many n. Then I fix one such index, say $n_0 \geq N$ such that $\beta - \epsilon/2 \leq f \leq f_{n_0} \leq \beta + \epsilon/2$

$\implies$ $|f_{n_0} - \beta| < \epsilon/2$
Thus, for all $n\geq N$

$|f_n - \beta| = |f_n - f_{n_0} + f_{n_0}- \beta| \leq |f_n - f_{n_0}| + |f_{n_0}- \beta| \leq \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon$

Hence, $\mathscr{E}(\Omega)$ is a complete metric space. I don't believe this is right since I didn't use the definition for the convergence of the smooth functions.

Define $\mathscr{E}(\Omega)$ as the space of all smooth functions, $\varphi \in C^{\infty}(\Omega)$, equipped with convergence (topology) as follows:

$\varphi_{n} \rightarrow \varphi \text{ in } \mathscr{E}(\Omega) \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty$
if for every compact K $\subset \Omega$ and multi-index $\alpha$,
$\partial_{x}^{\alpha} \varphi_{n} \Rightarrow \partial_{x}^{\alpha} \varphi\text{ uniformly on } K \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty$.

$\mathscr{E}(\Omega)$ can be equipped with semi-norms and that provide the same convergence. Indeed, define for every given compact $K$ and $l$ the semi-norm

$p_{K,l}(\varphi) = \sum_{|\alpha| \leq l}$ sup$_{K}|D^{\alpha}\varphi|$

Thus we have semi-norms,

$\varphi \rightarrow \sum_{|\alpha| \leq l}$ sup$_{K}|D^{\alpha}\varphi|$

where $K$ ranges over all compact subsets of $\Omega$ and $l$ over all integers $\geq 0$

Comment: Note that notation is often not universal, especially for spaces. What is the space $\mathcal{E}(\Omega)$ here?

Comment: If you are talking about the space of $C^{\infty}$ functions on $\Omega$ you should also write down how the topology is defined. Without using the semi-norms that define the topology you cannot prove this result.

Comment: What metric is used on $\mathscr{E}(\Omega)$?

Comment: Suppose the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=f(x)=x$, obviously a Cauchy sequence belonging to $\mathcal{E}(\mathbb{R})$, Where does your "proof" fail?

Comment: If a topology is defined by seminorms $q_i$, a sequence $(f_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in the topology iff for each $i$ the sequence $(q_i(f_n))_n$ is Cauchy in the reals.

Comment: Sooo... am I correct? I just wasn’t sure that using such a rudimentary approach without the semi-norm definition would satisfy as a proof

Comment: What do you mean with $\sup Q$? Normally one takes $\sup$ over a set of reals. But $Q$ is a set of functions. Those are not linearly ordered. Throughout your "proof" you seem to treat the functions as reals, which they are not.